# Verify SAML assertion signature in .Net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, saml, signature

I have an XML of SAML assertion and I can't figure out what is wrong with this verification. Also I cannot use any libraries from the full .Net Framework (here I use  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` and  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml` packages).

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));            
RsaSecurityKey key = new RsaSecurityKey(RSA.Create());            
SamlSerializer ser = new SamlSerializer();
var assertion = ser.ReadAssertion(xmlReader);            
assertion.Signature.Verify(key);
```

The `ReadAssertion` is OK and the certificate is there inside `Signature.KeyInfo.X509Data`.
Or maybe I'm using a wrong SecurityKey and `RsaSecurityKey` is not the right choice for this? I'm not really sure how to interpret the `Signature` part of this:

```
        <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_466e5c77-b0d7-4c5e-a652-ec66f520302e" Issuer="http://www.example.com/sts.6" IssueInstant="2021-11-02T12:55:44.273Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
            <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2021-11-02T12:55:44.273Z" NotOnOrAfter="2021-11-02T16:55:44.273Z">
                <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                    <saml:Audience>https://www.example.com/prod</saml:Audience>
                </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
            </saml:Conditions>
            <saml:AttributeStatement>
                ...
            </saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="URN:IVIS:100001:AM.BANK-SWED" AuthenticationInstant="2021-11-02T12:55:44.085Z">
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:ivis:100001:name.id-viss">PK:08028710315</saml:NameIdentifier>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
                <saml:SubjectLocality IPAddress="87.242.186.212"/>
            </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_466e5c77-b0d7-4c5e-a652-ec66f520302e">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <DigestValue>VAOQYRxyrO+pJs9+pGjQWOXoR5SFTKHhG3lmpFS0TeQ=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>BjslVMuLfUcbNMiJPpTiqmr/WgI/ZuzXfRV...gGFrdW/cH/BFrJfiq9oWlQcFLVD/GFsq3XQw==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>MIIF7jCCBNagAwIBAgIKEqni0gABAAABQz...4LsBscidh0/nNcAJwOVlCfw==</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </saml:Assertion>
```